# Javascript return vs new

Tags: javascript

I've done some tests and I'm wondering why a `new TestOne()` evaluates to a new instance of the function but a `new TestThree()` evaluates to the return value.

It appears that this depends on whether an object is returned or a primitive type. I'd expect `new TestThree()` to evaluate to `TestThree {}` (an instance of it). What happens to the instance of `TestThree` that's created by `new`?

What are the rules behind this and why?

```
function TestOne() {
    return 123;
}

new TestOne(); // TestOne {}
TestOne(); // 123

function TestTwo() {
}

new TestTwo(); // TestTwo {}
TestTwo(); // undefined

function TestThree() {
    return new TestOne();
}

new TestThree(); // TestOne {}
TestThree(); // TestOne {}
```

Comment: Looks like if you return an object that is used. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description "The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead."

Comment: Ah, that answers my question- thank you.